# How can I earn a bunch of arrowheads quickly in Psychonauts?

Tags: psychonauts

I've finished Lungfishopolis, blown my stash of arrowheads on the magnet-thing and a couple of psy cores, and just started the Milkman Conspiracy.

And now I'm suddenly shown a warning that says "You should have the Cobweb thing, or you won't get far in the Milkman Conspiracy." It costs 800 arrowheads. I just spent all of my arrowheads. I am sad. (And I've tried doing the Milkman Conspiracy anyway. I can do some stuff, but I need some particular items to get further in the game. Those items are, as far as I can tell, behind the cobwebs that block off some of the houses.)

I've already bought the dowsing rod and dug up about a half-dozen deep arrowheads, so that source of easy money is already partly depleted.  **Is there any other way to make 800 arrowheads in a relative hurry?** I'm not particularly fond of grinding; I've only earned a cumulative total of around 500 arrowheads so far.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The consensus from [various](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/924711-psychonauts/52486525) [forum](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/561517-psychonauts/51722273) [posts](http://www.drunkduck.com/forum/topic/153129/) seems to be that the best way to collect arrowheads quickly is to use the dowsing rod. You say you've already bought that, so that's good! It may take some time to dig up 800 arrowheads' worth, but this [map of Deep Arrowhead locations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80GgR.jpg) may be of use.

Note, I haven't verified its accuracy.

Comment: From experience, using the dowsing rod will get you the amount you need in less than an hour of searching.

Comment: I used that map to find all the arrowheads in the Campfire, GPC, and Lake areas, and can verify that it is accurate for at least those locations. I had tons of extra arrowheads after buying everything, so you probably only need to clear out the deep arrowheads in one or two regions. Another tip: on a computer, make the searching easier by using [a script to continuously press F](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/117631/28422).

Comment: Is the image still available?  It appears to have been eaten by Photobucket's ToS changes and needs re-uploading...

Comment: Here is an updated image link: https://i.imgur.com/0gCl1oM.jpg